# Apps "cannot be opened because of a problem"

Tags: macos, applications

Whenever I am trying to open an app, most of them won't open with the error as below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am really helpless here. Is there is any issue with my machine?

I have a Ubuntu background and recently started using OS X.

Mac version :

[image]

Comment: What version of OSX?  Go to the  menu and select "about this Mac"

Comment: Tip: take a screenshot of a window by pressing ⇧⌘3 then Space, then click a window, or ⌥-click to remove the shadow.

Comment: @grgarside... ⇧⌘4 then Space ;)

Comment: I wonder if this is that expired certificate issue? Do you have the latest version of Mac OS?

Comment: @bjbk : added the version screenshot

Comment: @SteveChambers : man...you are life saver!!! there were 5 updates one of which was related to MacOS.I did that as you _wondered_ and voila!!!
But on the other side, this is wrong, not letting apps opens just because user is not updating is bad, i realise Ubuntu is much much better!!

Comment: Apple let a vital certificate expire that signed a bunch of apps. Bad on them, but keeping your O/S updated in this day and age is more than just "*A Good Idea*" Any OS manufacturer can and has made egregious mistakes. The trick is, how they respond. And Apple cleaned this one up pretty quickly,

Comment: @SteveChambers : agreed on last point...why not post your comment as answer, i'll mark it accepted!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple let a vital App Store certificate apply, unfortunately. Update your OS and that should fix the issue.

While this does not speak well for Apple, many OS manufacturers have had critical (or if you will stupid) flaws in their OS. Which makes it a good idea to keep up to date on released updates in the App store.

Comment: For a similar certificate issue, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215332/many-os-x-app-store-apps-are-listed-as-app-is-damaged-and-cant-be-opened ...  Optimists say Apple's speedy recovery is a sign they're improving.