# Apps installed from App Store do not work

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore

I have a 15-inch MacBook Pro Mid 2010 running on a fresh install of the last supported macOS version (High Sierra 10.13.6). I know this is really old, but except for the battery (which I removed from the laptop) it is still a great machine. Everything works fine except apps installed from the App Store do not start (downloading and installing works fine).

As an example, after downloading The Unarchiver, immediately after double-clicking on the app, I get the following error message:

> The Unarchiver quit unexpectedly. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

Again, this happens with **all apps** from the App Store (not just "The Unarchiver").

Strangely enough, apps installed not from the App Store work just fine. I tried installing Microsoft Teams, Discord, and Minecraft, and all apps are starting and working normally.

I digged around a bit and found out that maybe this problem is related to app signatures not working for the App Store somehow. For example, I verified the signature of "The Unarchiver" using the following command in my terminal:

```
$ codesign --verify --verbose /Applications/The\ Unarchiver.app
The Unarchiver.app: CSSMERR_TP_CERT_REVOKED
In architecture: x86_64
```

Signatures for apps downloaded outside the App Store are OK:

```
$ codesign --verify --verbose /Applications/Googe\ Chrome.app
Google Chrome.app: valid on disk
Google Chrome.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? I already contacted Apple Support, but they don't know either and they won't escalate this issue because both my MacBook and macOS High Sierra is too old (and therefore unsupported).

Also, this issue doesn't seem to be related with [Many OS X app store apps are listed as "app" is damaged and can't be opened](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215332/many-os-x-app-store-apps-are-listed-as-app-is-damaged-and-cant-be-opened), which gives a different error message.

Here is the crash log, which to me confirms that the certificate is invalid:

```
Process:               The Unarchiver [981]
Path:                  /Applications/The Unarchiver.app/Contents/MacOS/The Unarchiver
Identifier:            cx.c3.theunarchiver
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           The Unarchiver [981]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-11-21 11:46:23.541 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G66)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        8E417EB4-CE16-F300-F7D8-8C94E0C5F25B


Time Awake Since Boot: 710 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0 (cr2):
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100346000-0000000100392000 [  304K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  

Thread 0 Crashed:
0                                   0x00000001046ec19c _dyld_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007ffeef8b9c28
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00000001046ec19c  rfl: 0x0000000000000200  cr2: 0x0000000000000000
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     0


Binary Images:
       0x100346000 -        0x100391ff7 + (???) <4CC58FC2-E9C2-3F2E-8CBE-A89199F4203B> 
       0x1046eb000 -        0x104735acf + (551.4) <8A72DE9C-A136-3506-AA02-4BA2B82DCAF3> 

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 607
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=760K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=760K(100%)
Writable regions: Total=8408K written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=8408K(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        2 
Stack                             8192K        2 
__DATA                             320K        5 
__LINKEDIT                         156K        3 
__TEXT                             604K        3 
shared memory                        8K        3 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                             65.1M       12
```

I also get a bunch of errors in the console that might be related, e.g.

#### `sandboxd`

```
Sandbox: fseventsd(46) System Policy: deny(1) file-read-metadata /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store
Violation:       System Policy: deny(1) file-read-metadata /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store 
Process:         fseventsd [46]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/Support/fseventsd
Load Address:    0x10627b000
Identifier:      fseventsd
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       x86_64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]
Responsible:     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/Support/fseventsd [46]
User ID:         0

Date/Time:       2020-11-22 16:16:27.772 GMT+1
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G66)
Report Version:  8


MetaData: {"signing-id":"com.apple.fseventsd","process":"fseventsd","platform_binary":"yes","primary-filter-value":"\/private\/var\/db\/ConfigurationProfiles\/Store","rootless-class":"com.apple.rootless.storage.ConfigurationProfilesPrivate","rdev":0,"hardware":"Mac","pid":46,"vnode-type":"DIRECTORY","flags":21,"platform-binary":true,"profile":"platform","summary":"deny(1) file-read-metadata \/private\/var\/db\/ConfigurationProfiles\/Store","rootless-flags":128,"platform-policy":true,"process-path":"\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreServices.framework\/Versions\/A\/Frameworks\/FSEvents.framework\/Versions\/A\/Support\/fseventsd","primary-filter":"path","target":"\/private\/var\/db\/ConfigurationProfiles\/Store","action":"deny","build":"Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G66)","profile-flags":0,"path":"\/private\/var\/db\/ConfigurationProfiles\/Store","uid":501,"normalized_target":["private","var","db","ConfigurationProfiles","Store"],"operation":"file-read-metadata","errno":1}

Thread 0 (id: 537):
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7239e20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7239df64 mach_msg_server + 369
2   fseventsd                       0x000000010627cbb6
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff72257015 start + 1
4   fseventsd                       0x0000000000000001

Thread 1 (id: 574):
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff723a7a16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   fseventsd                       0x0000000106287343
2   fseventsd                       0x00000001062877a5
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f661 _pthread_body + 340
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f50d _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256ebf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 2 (id: 575):
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff723a828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256ebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3 (id: 585):
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7239e20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00007fff4a382ff5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00007fff4a382347 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00007fff4a3819b7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00007fff4a3bfe23 CFRunLoopRun + 99
5   fseventsd                       0x000000010627ed7f
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f661 _pthread_body + 340
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f50d _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256ebf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 4 (id: 586):
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff723a9142 read + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f661 _pthread_body + 340
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f50d _pthread_body + 0
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256ebf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 5 (id: 587):
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff723a7a16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   fseventsd                       0x0000000106283855
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f661 _pthread_body + 340
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f50d _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256ebf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 6 (id: 3250):
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff723a8cf2 lstat$INODE64 + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f661 _pthread_body + 340
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f50d _pthread_body + 0
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256ebf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7 (id: 4051):
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff723a7a16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   fseventsd                       0x000000010628389f
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f661 _pthread_body + 340
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f50d _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256ebf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 8 (id: 17324):
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff723a8cf2 lstat$INODE64 + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f661 _pthread_body + 340
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256f50d _pthread_body + 0
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7256ebf9 thread_start + 13

Binary Images:
       0x10627b000 -        0x10628bfff  fseventsd (1239.50.1) <357b06be-3f03-37a6-8569-4a06ed093172> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/Support/fseventsd
    0x7fff4a300000 -     0x7fff4a79aff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1454.90) <f320589a-8600-3244-9b55-a645f7eaab35> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff72256000 -     0x7fff72273ff7  libdyld.dylib (551.4) <81bf3a82-5719-3b54-aba9-76c82d932cac> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff7238b000 -     0x7fff723b1ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (4570.71.2) <f22b8d73-69d8-36d7-bf66-7f9ac70c08c2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff7256c000 -     0x7fff72577fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (301.50.1) <0e51ccba-91f2-34e1-bf2a-feefd3d321e4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
```

#### `apsd`

```
Failed entitlement check 'com.apple.private.secure-apsclient' for <private>
Failed entitlement check 'com.apple.private.aps-connection-initiate' for <private>
```

#### `mdmclient`

```
Connection Invalid for service com.apple.apsd
```

Comment: These are applications you downloaded from the Store *after* reinstalling HS?

Comment: Yes. I did a fresh install of HS (even wiped all partitions), and then installed apps from the App Store (e.g. The Unarchiver).

Comment: Just to be clear, you get that error message about the unarchiver when you launch **any** App Store app or was that just an example of what app store apps do when launched? Also I would be tempted to run the last Combo Update for High Sierra. Combo updates often fix odd issues with macOS.

Comment: No, "The Unarchiver" was just an example &ndash; I get that message for every app in the app store (but with the corresponding app name of course). I have all available updates installed, is the combo update something different? If so, where can I download it?

Comment: Search for combo update High Sierra and pick the latest one you see on apple.com

Comment: The latest combo update is 10.13.6 which I already have, including all security updates.

Comment: Attach the crash logs please.

Comment: I added the crash log and some potentially related errors.

Comment: I experience exactly the same problem. I read somewhere that it might be related to the startup disk being formatted as HFS+ instead of APFS. I haven't tried yet but my drive is formatted as HFS+ and was not automatically converted to APFS during install (maybe because of it being a Samsung SSD)...

Comment: I actually did format with HFS+ instead of APFS! When I have time I'll try and re-install on an APFS volume instead. If you beat me to it please let me know how it worked out.

Comment: Tried every possible combination of installation. But sooner or later the error pops up. On El Capitan, same machine, I have no issues. Also for the first x minutes after installation everything works fine...

Comment: Oh no, that's bad news. Thanks for testing, it looks like Apple really wants us to buy new hardware...

Comment: It seems like resetting the SMC and NVRAM might have solved the issue. At least I can now successfully start "The Unarchiver" after installing it from the App Store. Really weird, but I guess that's what you get from using a 10+ year old computer.

Answer (score -1):

All the App Store apps are 64 bit I think and they won't run on your computer. You need 32 bit apps.  The apps you download from other sites may well be 32 bits.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because the [Intel Core i5-540M](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/43544/intel-core-i5-540m-processor-3m-cache-2-53-ghz.html) supports 64bit instructions.